# .NET 3.0 or later Socket Bible

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c#-3.0, c#-4.0

is there a Bible for Sockets programming in .NET that utilizes the 3.0 or later framework?  An example of the caliber that I am looking for should be on the level of Concurrent Programming on Windows by Joe Duffy if this were a .NET threading and concurrency question.

C# is my prefered source code book samples but any language on the .NET framework are welcome.

I'm looking for a book, but if there exists a website or blog of similar content, they are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shameless self-promotion: I maintain a [FAQ on .NET TCP/IP on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html). It covers things that a lot of books skip over (in particular, proper application protocol design). It doesn't cover things like comparing the three socket APIs (synchronous, async via Begin/End, async via Async) or higher-level APIs (`TcpClient`, `NetworkStream`, etc).

CPoW is pretty hefty. I doubt there's a .NET sockets book that addresses the subject to that depth (though I haven't read Adam's recommendation). The best resources I've found are just the classic socket books (e.g., Stevens volume 1). Since the `Socket` class is almost exactly a 1:1 mapping to WinSock calls, this approach worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I've purchased and read this book:

TCP/IP Sockets in C#: A Practical Guide for Programmers

[http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Sockets-Practical-Programmers/dp/0124660517/ref=pd_cp_b_1_img](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124660517)

Its not specific to 3.0, but its a very good book - covers most of what you'd expect to see, and as a beginner to sockets (like I was) it answers the questions you find yourself trying to Google :-)